# Outliers for N=4

Tags: outliers, exploratory-data-analysis

If you have 4 observations, can you have an outlier? Consider any value outside (Lower fourth-1.5(Fourth Spread), upper fourth+1.5(fourth spread)) as an outlier.

Comment: I believe your definition of outlier matches the one used in the procedures `boxplot` and `boxplot.stats` in R. Code `x = c(1,2,3,100); boxplot.stats(x)$out` returns
`numeric(0)`, meaning that no outliers are detected. // If you look carefully at definitions of 'fourth' and 'fourth spread' and what they mean for a sample of size 4, I think you will conclude that the answer is No.

Comment: _Caution:_ Some programs/textbooks use 'quartiles' instead of 'fourths' to make boxplots and to define outliers. And there are several different conventions for defining quartiles. So it is possible that some statistical programs/testbooks would call 100 an outlier in the example of my first Comment. // I don't think this Caution applies to your question, but you should know there may be room for disagreement on this concept. // Some programs require at least n=5 observations even to make a boxplot, which seems a sensible policy.

Comment: More broadly, with so little information, it is hard to say if any of these observations is or is not common to the rest.